# next_payment_date Paypal IPN not working (Recurring_payments)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Paypal is returning this:
[next_payment_date] => 03:00:00 Mar 14, 2014 PDT 
and this
[time_created] => 10:47:34 Mar 14, 2014 PDT.

The billing cycle is set to a month, why is Paypal returning the same date for the next_payment_date? It should be on April. Where could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And have the first payment been taken ? When you create new profile first payment is set on the same day as start date is set. Mext month you should get when you will receive first recurring payment notification.